# How can I stop divs from overlapping when window is smaller?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

Making a log in page and have 2 divs of main content in a section. The first Div contains my logo, input prompts, and buttons for login/password reset. The second one is meant to be a footer with social media links. On a full size window my logo is to the left of the login prompt and the social media bar is at the bottom like it should. However, When I make the window a smaller height the login buttons overlap into the social media bar at the bottom. And since the page is set up to place the logo on top of the input form after a certain width it overlaps all the way to the logo when the window is a small square. I want it to stay separate. and to be scrollable if it cannot adjust fully to a small window.

I have tried the following media query to try to solve this but it has no effect when the window is smaller.

```
.hcustom {
    height: calc(100% - 73px);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .hcustom {
        height: 100%; //I have also tried with 100vh
    }
}
```

I tried this with and without the "Screen" word because i was not sure if i was doing it right

Another close solution I had was that i set hcustom  to min-height:100vh; and this worked perfectly for a smaller window BUT On a larger window it left a huge space between my first div and the social media bar at the bottom which made a large window scrollable.

The following is my index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">  
        <meta name="Description" content = "Login">
        <title>LOGIN</title>

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="loginStyles.css">

    
    </head>

    <body>
    <section class="vh-100">

     <!--FIRST Div -->        
         <div class="container-fluid hcustom">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">

                <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 text-center">
                    <img src="img/main-logo.png"
                    alt="Login image" class="img-fluid" style="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 offset-xl-1">       
                    <form action="login.php" method="post">   
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
                                <h2>Login</h2>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <br>

                        <?php if(isset($_GET['error'])) {?>
                            <p class="error"><?php echo $_GET['error']; ?></p>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                            <input type="text" id="userN" name="usrname" placeholder="Enter User Name"
                            class="form-control form-control-lg" />

                            <label class="form-label" for="userN">
                                User Name
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-outline mb-3">
                            <input type="password" id="passW" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"
                            class="form-control form-control-lg" />

                            <label class="form-label" for="passW">
                                Password
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <!-- Checkbox -->
                            <div class="form-check mb-0">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="rem" />
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="rem">
                                    Remember me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#!" class="text-body">Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class= "pt-1 my-3 text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                            style="padding-left: 2.5rem; padding-right: 2.5rem;">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center mt-4 pt-2">  
                            <p class="small fw-bold mt-2 pt-1 mb-0">Don't have an account? 
                                <a href="" class="link-danger">Register</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
    
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- Second Div --> 
       <div
        class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row text-center text-md-start justify-content-between py-4 px-4 px-xl-5 bg-primary ">
            
            <div class="text-white mb-3 mb-md-0">
            Social Media 
            </div>
           

            <div>
                <a href="" class="text-white me-4 text-decoration-none">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-facebook" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M16 8.049c0-4.446-3.582-8.05-8-8.05C3.58 0-.002 3.603-.002 8.05c0 4.017 2.926 7.347 6.75 7.951v-5.625h-2.03V8.05H6.75V6.275c0-2.017 1.195-3.131 3.022-3.131.876 0 1.791.157 1.791.157v1.98h-1.009c-.993 0-1.303.621-1.303 1.258v1.51h2.218l-.354 2.326H9.25V16c3.824-.604 6.75-3.934 6.75-7.951z"/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="text-white me-4 text-decoration-none" >
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-youtube" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8.051 1.999h.089c.822.003 4.987.033 6.11.335a2.01 2.01 0 0 1 1.415 1.42c.101.38.172.883.22 1.402l.01.104.022.26.008.104c.065.914.073 1.77.074 1.957v.075c-.001.194-.01 1.108-.082 2.06l-.008.105-.009.104c-.05.572-.124 1.14-.235 1.558a2.007 2.007 0 0 1-1.415 1.42c-1.16.312-5.569.334-6.18.335h-.142c-.309 0-1.587-.006-2.927-.052l-.17-.006-.087-.004-.171-.007-.171-.007c-1.11-.049-2.167-.128-2.654-.26a2.007 2.007 0 0 1-1.415-1.419c-.111-.417-.185-.986-.235-1.558L.09 9.82l-.008-.104A31.4 31.4 0 0 1 0 7.68v-.123c.002-.215.01-.958.064-1.778l.007-.103.003-.052.008-.104.022-.26.01-.104c.048-.519.119-1.023.22-1.402a2.007 2.007 0 0 1 1.415-1.42c.487-.13 1.544-.21 2.654-.26l.17-.007.172-.006.086-.003.171-.007A99.788 99.788 0 0 1 7.858 2h.193zM6.4 5.209v4.818l4.157-2.408L6.4 5.209z"/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="text-white me-4 text-decoration-none">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-instagram" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8 0C5.829 0 5.556.01 4.703.048 3.85.088 3.269.222 2.76.42a3.917 3.917 0 0 0-1.417.923A3.927 3.927 0 0 0 .42 2.76C.222 3.268.087 3.85.048 4.7.01 5.555 0 5.827 0 8.001c0 2.172.01 2.444.048 3.297.04.852.174 1.433.372 1.942.205.526.478.972.923 1.417.444.445.89.719 1.416.923.51.198 1.09.333 1.942.372C5.555 15.99 5.827 16 8 16s2.444-.01 3.298-.048c.851-.04 1.434-.174 1.943-.372a3.916 3.916 0 0 0 1.416-.923c.445-.445.718-.891.923-1.417.197-.509.332-1.09.372-1.942C15.99 10.445 16 10.173 16 8s-.01-2.445-.048-3.299c-.04-.851-.175-1.433-.372-1.941a3.926 3.926 0 0 0-.923-1.417A3.911 3.911 0 0 0 13.24.42c-.51-.198-1.092-.333-1.943-.372C10.443.01 10.172 0 7.998 0h.003zm-.717 1.442h.718c2.136 0 2.389.007 3.232.046.78.035 1.204.166 1.486.275.373.145.64.319.92.599.28.28.453.546.598.92.11.281.24.705.275 1.485.039.843.047 1.096.047 3.231s-.008 2.389-.047 3.232c-.035.78-.166 1.203-.275 1.485a2.47 2.47 0 0 1-.599.919c-.28.28-.546.453-.92.598-.28.11-.704.24-1.485.276-.843.038-1.096.047-3.232.047s-2.39-.009-3.233-.047c-.78-.036-1.203-.166-1.485-.276a2.478 2.478 0 0 1-.92-.598 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-.6-.92c-.109-.281-.24-.705-.275-1.485-.038-.843-.046-1.096-.046-3.233 0-2.136.008-2.388.046-3.231.036-.78.166-1.204.276-1.486.145-.373.319-.64.599-.92.28-.28.546-.453.92-.598.282-.11.705-.24 1.485-.276.738-.034 1.024-.044 2.515-.045v.002zm4.988 1.328a.96.96 0 1 0 0 1.92.96.96 0 0 0 0-1.92zm-4.27 1.122a4.109 4.109 0 1 0 0 8.217 4.109 4.109 0 0 0 0-8.217zm0 1.441a2.667 2.667 0 1 1 0 5.334 2.667 2.667 0 0 1 0-5.334z"/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-book-half" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8.5 2.687c.654-.689 1.782-.886 3.112-.752 1.234.124 2.503.523 3.388.893v9.923c-.918-.35-2.107-.692-3.287-.81-1.094-.111-2.278-.039-3.213.492V2.687zM8 1.783C7.015.936 5.587.81 4.287.94c-1.514.153-3.042.672-3.994 1.105A.5.5 0 0 0 0 2.5v11a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.455c.882-.4 2.303-.881 3.68-1.02 1.409-.142 2.59.087 3.223.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .78 0c.633-.79 1.814-1.019 3.222-.877 1.378.139 2.8.62 3.681 1.02A.5.5 0 0 0 16 13.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.293-.455c-.952-.433-2.48-.952-3.994-1.105C10.413.809 8.985.936 8 1.783z"/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
               
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then this is my loginStyles.css

```
.hcustom {
    height: calc(100% - 73px);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .hcustom {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

I am using bootstrap 5

Comment: Where are you experiencing this issue? I've tested your original HTML (without your `.hcustom` rules) on both Firefox and Chrome (Desktop, Responsive design view), and there was no overlap.

Comment: @FiddlingAway This was on chrome.

Comment: Is the same issue present in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-taussig-u3c386)? Just ignore the module not found error - you can close it by clicking on the little x button in the upper right part of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change Image and Login div class to this `class="col-4"`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">  
        <meta name="Description" content = "Login">
        <title>LOGIN</title>

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="loginStyles.css">

        <style>

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <section class="vh-100">

     <!--FIRST Div -->        
         <div class="container-fluid hcustom">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <img src="img/main-logo.png"
                    alt="Login image" class="img-fluid" style="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-4">       
                    <form action="login.php" method="post">   
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
                                <h2>Login</h2>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <br>

                        <?php if(isset($_GET['error'])) {?>
                            <p class="error"><?php echo $_GET['error']; ?></p>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                            <input type="text" id="userN" name="usrname" placeholder="Enter User Name"
                            class="form-control form-control-lg" />

                            <label class="form-label" for="userN">
                                User Name
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-outline mb-3">
                            <input type="password" id="passW" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"
                            class="form-control form-control-lg" />

                            <label class="form-label" for="passW">
                                Password
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <!-- Checkbox -->
                            <div class="form-check mb-0">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="rem" />
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="rem">
                                    Remember me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#!" class="text-body">Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class= "pt-1 my-3 text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                            style="padding-left: 2.5rem; padding-right: 2.5rem;">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center mt-4 pt-2">  
                            <p class="small fw-bold mt-2 pt-1 mb-0">Don't have an account? 
                                <a href="" class="link-danger">Register</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
    
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- Second Div --> 
       <div
        class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row text-center text-md-start justify-content-between py-4 px-4 px-xl-5 bg-primary ">
            
            <div class="text-white mb-3 mb-md-0">
            Social Media 
            </div>
           

            <div>
                <a href="" class="text-white me-4 text-decoration-none">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-facebook" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="text-white me-4 text-decoration-none" >
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-youtube" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="text-white me-4 text-decoration-none">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-instagram" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-book-half" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    </svg>
                </a>
               
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a container to group both of your divs instead of putting them in two separate containers. That way you can make them take 50% each of the place that the container occupies.

Comment: I did place them in the same container but the top one still overflowed into the bottom. But even if it did work i would not want  the bottom one to take up 50%. I want the bottom div to stick to the bottom and not let the other div overflow over or under it.